# How to access data in Docker from my Django app?

Tags: django, docker, api, docker-compose

I am new to Docker so I wonder if I have 2 containers, a streamer that pushes data to the queue and vernemq which is the message queue.
How can I access the data to work with it in my django rest api app?
I was wondering is there a way to export or the data and create a separate database in django with it or it's not how it works?
Or is there a way to directly access the data in docker from django app.

Note the django rest api app is not in a docker Image.

Answer (score 0):

depends on how your current Django REST API is configured... if is looking at a Database? is it looking at a series of other your companies RESI APIs, etc?

I can edit this with more info once I  get a little more details. Don't have enough reputation to write a comment.

BUT I would say the best way if the Django app is looking at a database is to write a script to transfer code from the messaging queue and save to the database.

What I would say though is instead of using a message queue to just have the streamer push it directly to where you have your Django app looking.

Comment: Thank you for answering, yes the api is looking at a database. Can you tell me how to transfer code from the messaging queue and save to the database?

Comment: What messaging queue? I have used rabbitMQ before in this same example. What I did was write a script that reads that queue and then saves to the database. you can use a library like ponyORM to save if it is compatible.

Comment: vernemq is the messaging queue. Thanks a lot I will read more about ponyORM